# Manually collapse a CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

How can I manually collapse a `CollapingToolbarLayout` ?

I kept digging, but there are no **state** setters, no nothing.

Comment: You can try to set scrollY. Maybe this will help.

Comment: I tried, but I get a weird behavior from the Toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're using [`Android Support Library`](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html#) version 23 or higher, you can use a method of your [`AppBarLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html) - [`setExpanded(...)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html#setExpanded(boolean,%20boolean)).

Comment: makes sense. After all, the AppbarLayout is its container.